# integrate jquery with xml

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have worked with **jQuery and JSON** Object, but how does the data in the ***xml*** page can be  fetched and shown up using jQuery?
or   How the **data in the XML** file can be fetched and shown up on a page using jQuery?

Comment: Use AJAX. I'm not really sure what kind of answer you're expecting here?

Comment: yes. @RoryMcCrossan.. I've used ajax just as **topcat** suggested...
Thanks again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read through this tutorial http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

and I think what you want is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
url: "sites.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

}
});
```

from here : http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can process XML nodes using jQuery in exactly the same way as you can process HTML nodes:

```
$(response).find('somenode');
```

Assuming you've set `dataType` to `xml`, the response is already an XML document object. Just wrap it in a jQuery object and you can use `find` etc on it.

Comment: Just .html() method is not supported on xml object